# node js REPL console prints undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I am doing node REPL, I tried printing a statement on console like below. Along with the statement, it also printed undefined. How to understand this weird behaviour. Below is the code.

```
>console.log('Hello World!');
>Hello World!
 undefined
```

Comment: It's the return value of `console.log()`. The console shows you the completion value for your script so you can just write `5 + 5` and get 10 back without needing a `console.log`, for example.

Comment: cool. Thank you, got it.